# Reports on AWS from every 3 hours to every minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I need a little help, pointer in the right direction.

I'm tasked with transferring customer order data (for sales clothing) from onprem into the cloud for reporting purposes (read only). We work with AWS. The data sources are Oracle DB & mysql. I was going to use glue jobs, crawl the data sources and then move the data into say Dynamo db (NoSQl, fast) via step functions/lambdas, where the data would be linked up (lets say there is an ID field in each which links the data). Previously reporting on this data was fine to be about 2-3 hours old. I was going to set a schedule on the glue jobs every 2-3 hours.
This has now changed.
I'd now want to make the data as close to real time as possible (colleagues are starting to ask for it). Data being a minute or two old (or better) will be good enough.

Is what I'm thinking of doing above the right approach for what I'd like to achieve (only increase the frequency for crawling the source data)? Or should I look at something else?

note: I haven't made the system yet (I've only toyed about with Dynamo, glue jobs and step functions).

So, in AWS is there a better approach, I'd like to hear what my options are (advantages/disadvantages etc).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Lambda function can be written to get a data source and update a DynamoDB table. You can use the AWS SDK to write the Lambda functions to perform AWS Service operations; for example, update a DynamoDB table. If you write multiple Lambda functions, then you are correct - you can use them together via AWS Step Functions to create a workflow.

The nice thing here is if you do create an AWS Step Functions workflow that you need to run on a schedule, you can create another Lambda function that uses the AWS Step Functions API to dynamically execute the workflow by using the **startExecution** operation.

Overall, your thinking is on the right path. I would recommend Lambda functions that are used in an AWS Step Functions workflow that can be invoked every so often by another Lambda function that fires according to CRON and it invokes the **startExecution** operation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I'll start building out a very basic structure of that on AWS to see how it plays. For reporting, lets say the reports will be build in powerbi. I wonder, when I grab the data from the source system, will power bi reading the data be any quicker if the data is in dynamo db, versus say, having the data dumped into s3 buckets. (just thinking out loud)

Comment: I recommend coding a few possibilities and then do some testing/performance testing, etc. You are on the right track however.